# generating calendar with given month and year

Tags: java, calendar

How to generate the `Calendar` when month and year are the input parameters?

Note: I have already calculated the number of days a month contains.

Comment: "Note: I have already calculated the number of days a month contains." a) You probably did it wrong. It's hard to do it right - there are many rules. b) There is already code in the framework that does this for you. Why write it yourself?

Comment: @Mark Byers: is there any link with complete code?

Answer (score 2):

Why not like this?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month); // 0-based
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
```

Of course, I should suggest using [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) `DateTime` instead of `Calendar` for date-time operations.

Comment: what are we setting in to the calender instance and how to proceed?

Comment: you said you have the month and year. That's what you said. (see the javadoc)

Comment: ok we are setting month and year but what will be the next step? I have not used calender instance before. So any detailed description?

Comment: I don't know - what do you want to do with it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY); // note this is a 0-11 value for jan-dec
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 20); // pick the 20th day...or whatever from input
```

Note that doing it this way will automatically recalculate the rest of the fields (such as how many days are in the month, etc).  You can also use the add() function on Calendar to add days and it'll take all of that into account as well.

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 0):

## Using java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy `Calendar` & `Date` classes.

## `YearMonth`

The [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents, well, a year and a month, without any date or time-of-day or time zone.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH );
```

## `LocalDate`

You can generate a `LocalDate` from that.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth();
```

If you want the dates in between, loop. Increment the date by one day at a time. Check to see if each day is still in the same `YearMonth`. If not, you have incremented too far and can stop.

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>( 31 );
LocalDate localDate = ym.atDay( 1 );
while ( YearMonth.from( localDate ).equals( ym ) {
    dates.add( localDate );
    // Set up the next loop.
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).